# cannot find symbol - constructor in Java

Tags: java

i get the cannot find symbol - constructor Occupant(Position)
when i try to compile the sub class Animal of Occupant

```
public class Occupant
{
protected Position position;
public String string=" ";
protected String name;
protected String description;

public Occupant(Position position, String name, String description){
    this.position=position;
    this.name=name;
    this.description=description;

}






public class Animal extends Occupant
{
protected String name;
protected String description;
protected double dangerLevel;
protected String stringRepresentation;
protected Position position; 

public Animal(Position position, String name, String description, double dangerLevel) {
    super(position);
    super(name);
    super(description);
    this.position=position;
    this.dangerLevel=dangerLevel;
    this.name=name;
    this.description=description;

}
```

why do i get this error? thanks

Comment: that was like watching a firing squad of knowledge

Answer (score 3):

As well as all the other answers correctly pointing out that you should call the single super-constructor with three arguments, rather than trying to do it one argument at a time, it's worth mentioning that a constructor can only have *one* `super(...)` call or *one* `this(...)` call.

*Every* constructor (other than the one in `Object` itself) performs exactly one chaining operation:

- Implicitly, if you don't specify anything else, you can chain to a parameterless super-constructor. So:

  ```
  Foo(int x)
  {
  }
  ```

  is equivalent to

  ```
  Foo(int x)
  {
      super();
  }
  ```

  ... so obviously there has to *be* an accessible parameterless constructor to work
- It can chain explicitly to a super-constructor, as per your example
- It can chain to another constructor in the same class, e.g.

  ```
  Foo()
  {
      this(10);
  }
  ```

  The chaining within a class isn't allow to cause cycles. (You can't have two constructors which chain to each other.)

The chaining occurs *before* any variable initializers are executed, has to come at the start of the constructor body, and again, there is *exactly one* of the above options.

Answer (score 2):

`super(position)` calls a constructor on the parent type with one argument. Since a one argument constructor doesn't exist, the compilation fails. Try this instead:

`super(position,name,description);`

Answer (score 2):

Because you are calling constructors of the parent class, which don't exist:

```
super(position);
super(name);
super(description);
```

Answer (score 2):

You get this error because when you call super(...) you're essentially calling Occupant(...).  Since Occupant(...) has 3 parameters, super(...) must as well.  Try using:

```
super(position, name, description);
```

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
super(position);
super(name);
super(description);
```

with

```
super(position, name, description);
```

Answer (score 1):

The is no constructor of class `Occupant` that receives 1 argument.

This:

```
super(position);
super(name);
super(description);
```

should be :

```
super(position, name, description);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not call a sup construcotr that way.

Please use

```
public Animal(Position position, String name, String description, double dangerLevel) {
            super(position, name, description);
            this.position = position;
            this.dangerLevel = dangerLevel;
            this.name = name;
            this.description = description;

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the use of `super` in `Animal`.

Your `Occupant` class has a constructor of `Position, String, String`, hence your super should pass the same values.

The following `super` calls points to a non-existant `Occupant` constructors.

```
super(position);
super(name);
super(description);
```

Solution: Call the super class constructor by passing relevant fields (as mentioned above).

```
public Animal(Position position, String name, String description, double dangerLevel) {
    super(position, name, description);
    // other declarations..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public Occupant(Position position, String name, String description);
```

Parent class constructor takes three arguments but you are just passing one from derived class.

```
public Animal(Position position, String name, String description, double dangerLevel)  
{     
    super(position);     // Just passing one. 
    super(position, name, description);      // Do this instead
```